# Removing numbers from text using C#

Tags: c#, text

I have a text file for processing, which has some numbers. I want JUST text in it, and nothing else. I managed to remove the punctuation marks, but how do I remove the numbers? I want this using C# code.

Also, I want to remove words with length greater than 10. How do I do that using Reg Expressions?

Comment: What does the file look like (example input/output???), and where's the code you have to remove punctuation?

Comment: Could you provide sample data in your file?

Comment: Maybe you can show the some code so that the community can see what you have tried?

Answer (score 31):

You can do this with a regex:

```
string withNumbers = // string with numbers
string withoutNumbers = Regex.Replace(withNumbers, "[0-9]", "");
```

Use this regex to remove words with more than 10 characters:

```
[\w]{10, 100}
```

100 defines the max length to match. I don't know if there is a quantifier for min length...

Comment: This is how I would do it too. Prachi - Remember the extra using directive to System.Text.RegularExpressions if you don't have it already!

Comment: Also, I want to remove words with length greater than 10. How do i do that using Reg Expressions?

Answer (score 3):

Only letters and nothing else (because I see you also want to remove the punctuation marks)

`Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use string.Join:

```
string s = "asdasdad34534t3sdf43534";
s = string.Join(null, System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(s, "[\\d]"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx) method should do the trick.

```
// regex to match any digit
var regex = new Regex("\d");                     
// replace all matches in input with empty string
var output = regex.Replace(input, String.Empty);
```