# Creating a char array for TrimEnd and TrimStart

Tags: c#, trim

I have to remove leading and trailing numeric characters from a string in our web-service client project as for some reason the web-service at the other end in Norway won't accept `Nicosia 1121` as a string...

So I decided to build a little re-useable function that would do it:

```
public static string CleanNosFromStr(string text, char charsToRemove)
{ 
    var CleanedStr = text.TrimEnd(charsToRemove).TrimStart(charsToRemove);
        return CleanedStr.ToString();
    }
```

and I wanted to call it like this:

```
char chars2Remove= new string("0,1,2,3,4, 5,6,7,8,9,0, ").Split(",");

wsSoapBody.CardCity = 
myextensions.CleanNosFromStr(aMessage[(int)cardCreate.CardCity].ToString(),chars2Remove);
```

But it won't compile...

The compilation errors I am getting are:

> The best overloaded method match for 'string.String(char*)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char*'

Where am I going wrong, and is there a better way?

Of course I could just use

```
wsSoapBody.CardCity = aMessage[(int)cardCreate.CardCity].ToString().TrimEnd
('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', ' ').
TrimStart('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', ' ');
```

but I'd prefer to have something re-useable.

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the compilation error message? (You should have included it...) Did you understand it? Do you understand that `char` is a *single* character, not an array?

Comment: Change it to char[] charsToRemove

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing numbers from text using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411530/removing-numbers-from-text-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I did read it, but didn't understand it enough. You are right, I will edit the question to include the compilation error.

Comment: What do you expect `new string("....")` to do?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I tried that as I wanted to create a string which I could convert to an array. It turns out I had missed some fundamentals, as explained by [rubidium-37](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2629311/rubidium-37) in the answer I accepted.

Comment: You should try to learn more about diagnosing problems though - as soon as you hit a compiler error you don't understand, you should stop rather than incurring more of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some points:

1. `text.TrimEnd(charsToRemove).TrimStart(charsToRemove)` can be shortened with `text.Trim(charsToRemove)`.
2. `Trim`, `TrimStart` and `TrimEnd` accepts single or multiple chars (see [String.Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).
3. Your code `new string("0,1,2,3,4, 5,6,7,8,9,0, ").Split(",")` should be `"0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, ".Split(',')`...
4. But it could be better expressed with `"0123456789 ".ToCharArray()`.

Finally your code could be:

```
private static readonly char[] NosCharsToRemove = "0123456789 ".ToCharArray();
public static string CleanNosFromStr(string text)
{ 
    return text.Trim(NosCharsToRemove);
}
```

and

```
wsSoapBody.CardCity = myextensions.CleanNosFromStr(aMessage[(int)cardCreate.CardCity].ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks for your expanation and well written answer.

Answer (score 2):

As you want remove all numbers from the string.

You can achieve it using linq to just filter all characters that are letters using [`Char.IsLetter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static string CleanNosFromStr(string text)
{ 
    var CleanedStr = new String(text.Where(x=>Char.IsLetter(x)).ToArray());
    return CleanedStr;
}
```

and use it :

```
wsSoapBody.CardCity = 
myextensions.CleanNosFromStr(aMessage[(int)cardCreate.CardCity].ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Regex. For example, this replaces any character between (and including) the values of `0` and `9`, with `""`, which essentially just removes numbers from the string.

```
public static string RemoveNumbersFromStr(string text)
{ 
    return Regex.Replace(text, "[0-9]", "");
}
```

And a use case:

```
wsSoapBody.CardCity = 
myextensions.RemoveNumbersFromStr(aMessage[(int)cardCreate.CardCity].ToString());
```

Or if you like being able to debug things more easily:

```
var message = aMessage[(int)cardCreate.CardCity];
string strMessage = message.ToString();

wsSoapBody.CardCity = myextensions.RemoveNumbersFromStr(strMessage);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but please would you add some explanation of the regex

Comment: It replaces any character between (and including) the values of `0` and `9`, with `""`. I'll add this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about a regular expression?

```
\d*(\w*)\d*
```

Comment: @AIW: Thanks for your answer, but please would you expand on your answer to add some explanation of the regex and how to use it

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a Regex:

```
Regex rg = new Regex("\\d+");
string test = "12345allo12345";
string result = rg.Replace(test, "");
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but please would you add some explanation of the regex.

Comment: Sure. The regex matches one or more "digits" anywhere in the string. Using the `Regex.Replace` means that anything that matches will be replaced by an empty string in this specific case.